# Returning the cheapest item

Tags: java, return

I am pretty new to Java, but what I am currenlty stuck is I am trying to return an item but it will return the cheapest item. In the book I am using, it says I have to "Add a method cheaper which takes another StoreItem.  It returns whichever item is cheaper, this item or the one passed in.", I am just confused on how you get it to return the cheapest item.

```
package cwk18;
import java.util.Collections;

    public class StoreItem {
       private String name;
       private double price;

    public StoreItem(){ // constructor
        name= "name unavailable";
        price = 1;
    }
    public StoreItem(String naming1,int val){ // parameterized construtor
        this();
        setName(naming1);
        setPrice(val);
    }
    public String getName(){ //name accessor
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(String newName){ // name mutator
        this.name = newName;
    }
    public double getPrice(){ // price accessor
        return this.price;
    }
    public void setPrice(int val){// price mutator
            this.price = val;
    }
    public void cheaper(StoreItem newItem){ 

    }
```

}

Comment: Well, you'll have to compare the price of the current item (`this.price`) with the price of the other item that was passed to the method.

Comment: And you'll need a return type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say this function is to return whichever item is cheaper. 
The function shouldn't be `void`

but `'The object name'`

```
public StoreItem cheaper(StoreItem newItem) \\before is public void cheaper(...
{ 
   if(this.price >newItem.getPrice())
   {
       return newItem;
   }
   else 
   {
       return this;  //this means return the current item
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to change your return type from:

```
    public void cheaper(StoreItem newItem){ 

    }
```

to

```
    public StoreItem cheaper(StoreItem newItem){ 

    }
```

Now you just need to use an `if statement` to compare prices of the `StoreItem` passed as `newItem` to the one that this class represents.